# How to understand the syntax of conditional, assignment and constant expressions?

Tags: c

From C11 Standard

1. > 6.5.15  Conditional operator
   >
   > Syntax
   >
   > ```
   > conditional-expression:
   >     logical-OR-expression
   >     logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
   > ```

   Is a logical-OR-expression a conditional-expression, because it is
   degeneration of a conditional expression?
2. > 6.5.16  Assignment operators
   >
   > Syntax
   >
   > ```
   > assignment-expression:
   >     conditional-expression
   >     unary-expression  assignment-operator  assignment-expression
   > ```

   Does it mean that a conditional-expression is an assignment
   expression? Why is it?
3. > 6.6  Constant expressions
   >
   > Syntax
   >
   > ```
   > constant-expression:    
   >     conditional-expression
   > ```

   Does the syntax of a constant expression mean that constant
   expression and constant-expression are the same concept?

Thanks.

Comment: Essentially, the grammar nonterminal *meow-expression* includes both actual *meow* expressions and every expression whose top-level operator is of higher precedence than *meow* (in fact, this is how the precedence of operators are specified in the standard).

Comment: Look at the entire grammar for expressions generally; they're mostly structured along those lines.  For example, _primary expression_ does not follow this layout, but the next one, _postfix-expression_ does: `postfix-expression:` —
`primary-expression` —
`postfix-expression [ expression ]` —
`postfix-expression ( argument-expression-listopt )` …  A postfix-expression is either a primary-expression or one of a sequence of possible postfix-expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conditional-expression`, `assignment-expression`, and `constant-expression` are nonterminals in the grammar. Their names should not be taken to imply that a `conditional-expression` has to actually involve a conditional operator, or that an `assignment-expression` has to involve an assignment; they are named for their positions in the precedence hierarchy.

In particular, `constant-expression` expands to `conditional-expression` because constant-ness is not a grammatical notion. It's not the grammar's job to exclude non-constants where a constant is required; that job is handled in other parts of a compiler. The grammar will allow any `conditional-expression` where a constant is required.

Comment: A *constant-expression* had better be constant, though. That nonterminal is only used in places where an actual constant expression is required.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "they are named for their positions in the precedence hierarchy." Is it correct that in the syntax of a nonterminal,  the second line is always another nonterminal which is right before the nonterminal in precedence order, and the third line and below are definitions of the nonterminal?

Comment: (2) A conditional expression isn't a constant expression, so why does "the grammar will allow any conditional-expression where a constant is required"?

Comment: @Tim: Why does your text editor allow you to write `f(x)` where a constant is required? It's not your text editor's job to enforce that, and it's not the grammar's job either. As for the syntax in which these grammar rules are expressed, each line after the first one (with the colon) is a sequence the nonterminal can expand to.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 6.5 is very poorly written and is hard to understand. The key is this:

C11 6.5/3

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.

Meaning that operator precedence is actually not specified explicitly anywhere in the standard! Instead we are supposed to look at the syntax for each operator and figure it out.

All operators build a chain of operator precedence, so for each sub chapter of 6.5, the previous group of operators is mentioned just to indicate that it has higher precedence.

Starting from the top we have `primary-expression` (6.5.1) with the highest precedence. In the next group, postfix operators, the previous group will be mentioned to show that it has higher precedence:

```
postfix-expression:
  primary-expression
  postfix-expression [ expression ]
  ...
```

This doesn't mean that primary expression is a postfix expression, but rather that the syntax for a postfix expression is `primary-expression postfix-expression ...`

It goes on like this throughout the whole chapter 6.5. It might sound royally stupid and that's just because it *is* royally stupid.

Note 85) tries to provide a bit of help:

> The syntax specifies the precedence of operators in the evaluation of an expression, which is the same
>   as the order of the major subclauses of this subclause, highest precedence first.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how to understand the syntax of constant-expression? 1) Does it not specify the definition of constant expressions? 2) Does it only specify that the operator of conditional expressions has a higher precedence than some operators in constant-expression? But the constant -expression may have arithmetic operators, which have higher precedence than the operators of conditional expressions.